# How to make GtkListStore store object attribute in a row?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'w trying to keep at ListStore non-text objects using snippet I found. These are the objects:

```
class Series(gobject.GObject, object):
 def __init__(self, title):
  super(Series, self).__init__()
  self.title = title

gobject.type_register(Series)

class SeriesListStore(gtk.ListStore):
 def __init__(self):
  super(SeriesListStore, self).__init__(Series)
  self._col_types = [Series]

 def get_n_columns(self):
  return len(self._col_types)

 def get_column_type(self, index):
  return self._col_types[index]

 def get_value(self, iter, column):
  obj = gtk.ListStore.get_value(self, iter, 0)
  return obj
```

And now I'm trying to make TreeView display it:

```
    ...
    liststore = SeriesListStore()
 liststore.clear()

 for title in full_conf['featuring']:
  series = Series(title)
  liststore.append([series])

 def get_series_title(column, cell, model, iter):
  cell.set_property('text', liststore.get_value(iter, column).title)
  return

 selected = builder.get_object("trvMain")
 selected.set_model(liststore)

 col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(_("Series title"))
 cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
 col.set_cell_data_func(cell, get_series_title)
 col.pack_start(cell)
 col.add_attribute(cell, "text", 0)

 selected.append_column(col)
    ...
```

But it fails with errors:

> GtkWarning:
>   gtk_tree_view_column_cell_layout_set_cell_data_func:
>   assertion `info != NULL' failed
>
>   col.set_cell_data_func(cell,
>   get_series_title)
>   Warning: unable to set property`text'
>   of type `gchararray' from value of
>   type`data+TrayIcon+Series'
>   window.show_all()
>   Warning: unable to set property `text'
>   of type`gchararray' from value of
>   type `data+TrayIcon+Series'
>   gtk.main()gtk.main()

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes in the second-to-last block.

1. > GtkWarning: gtk_tree_view_column_cell_layout_set_cell_data_func: assertion `info != NULL'

   In English, this means that the cell renderer is not in the column's list of cell renderers. You need to add the cell renderer to the column first before calling `set_cell_data_func`.
2. > Warning: unable to set property `text' of type `gchararray' from value of `typedata+TrayIcon+Series'

   This is because the `add_attribute` line causes GTK+ to try setting the cell text to a Series object, which of course fails. Just remove that line; the cell data func already takes care of setting the cell text.

In code:

```
col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(_("Series title"))
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
col.pack_start(cell)
col.set_cell_data_func(cell, get_series_title)
```