# Implementing GObject interfaces in Python

Tags: python, interface, pygobject

When using the Python 3 bindings of GTK3, is it possible to implement `gobject.GInterface` interfaces by subclassing them?

In my specific case, I want to write a custom [`Gtk.TreeModel`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/interfaces/TreeModel.html) implementation. Is it sufficient to just subclass it and implement all virtual methods (`do_*`)?
In my constructor, do I call the parent constructor via `super().__init__()` as usual?
Is there anything else I need to consider?
Or can I only implement interfaces in GTK's native C?

I'm getting various errors and it would help me to know whether the impossibility of doing this in Python in the first place could be a cause.

Comment: this could be useful : https://gist.github.com/andialbrecht/4463278 (simple googling)

Comment: @Hacketo: Thanks, I could solve my problem using your link. You could post it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it answered my question, I'm posting [Hacketo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538473/hacketo)'s answer as per [the commonly accepted guideline for questions answered in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).

Implementing gobject interfaces in Python does seem possible and an example specifically for `Gtk.TreeModel` can be found [here](http://gist.github.com/andialbrecht/4463278).