# GtkTreeView with multiple columns and GtkListStore with single custom type (in Python)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I'm trying to display properties of an object on different columns of a `Gtk.TreeView`. Say I have the following:

```
class MyClass(GObject.GObject):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
```

And I want to store instances in a `Gtk.ListStore` as shown below.

```
store = Gtk.ListStore(MyClass)
```

Now, when creating the `Gtk.TreeView`, I don't know how to specify that 2 columns must be rendered, one for the `first` property and the other for the `age` property.

```
view = Gtk.TreeView(model=store)
# Columns for first and age added here
...
```

These posts [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178743/gtk-3-0-how-to-use-a-gtk-treestore-with-custom-model-items) and [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488285/how-to-make-gtkliststore-store-object-attribute-in-a-row) somewhat explain how to use custom types, but only use 1 column (then the length of the number of columns in the `store` matches the number of columns in the `view`). I sounds like what I'm trying to do would be a common thing without needing any workarounds. Perhaps it's about sub-classing `Gtk.ListStore` to have it tell the `view` that it has several columns and how to fetch each value?

Also, how do I make so that changes to MyClass instances in the `store` are automatically notified and reflected on the `view`?

Comment: Note that your constructor should use `self.first = "John"`, and so on. The current version is no-op.

Comment: My earlier comment was not useful (so deleted) -- there's many questions here but I guess they all fit the title. Writing your own TreeModel is possible but it's not trivial (and I don't think matching a GObject to a store in a generic way is as easy as you think). There are examples, but unfortunately a lot of the python ones are very low quality... Mine is here: https://github.com/01org/dleyna-control/blob/master/src/msd/msd_generic_model.py -- there's a lot there you don't need but take a look at the `do_*()` functions: they implement TreeModel. You'll have to implement those functions.

Comment: @jku The OP probably doesn't need a whole custom model - a simple `ListStore` suits him fine, given a way to extract arbitrary data from objects inside it. The strangely-named `set_cell_data_func` is useful exactly for such a purpose, and ListStore's `gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT` can be used to store arbitrary Python instances. Combining the two solves the problem rather elegantly.

Comment: @user4815162342 You have a point. I assume that does not fulfill the (implied) requirement of getting object property changes automatically reflected on the view though?

Comment: @jku You're right, it doesn't. I think I simply missed the last paragraph where that requirement is spelled out. But implementing this is fairly straightforward if data changes are comparatively infrequent - a notification mechanism that gets hooked to a function performing `tree_view.queue_draw()` would do the trick. A smarter mechanism that only redraws part of the tree (or nothing, if nothing visible changes) would indeed require a custom `TreeModel` implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things: set up a `ListStore` with a single `TYPE_PYOBJECT` column, and then use a `set_cell_data_func` on the tree view columns to set the cell text from the appropriate object attributes.

Here is an example that demonstrates this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

tree_store = Gtk.ListStore(GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT)
tree_store.append([MyClass("foo", "bar", 15)])
tree_store.append([MyClass("baz", "qux", 100)])

def make_column(caption, getter):
    rend = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(caption, rend)
    def _set_cell_text(column, cell, model, it, ignored):
        obj = model.get_value(it, 0)
        cell.set_property('text', getter(obj))
    col.set_cell_data_func(rend, _set_cell_text)
    return col

view = Gtk.TreeView(tree_store)
view.append_column(make_column("First", lambda obj: obj.first))
view.append_column(make_column("Last", lambda obj: obj.last))
view.append_column(make_column("Age", lambda obj: '%d' % obj.age))

w = Gtk.Window()
w.add(view)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: This is promising. I got it working on Gtk3 almost verbatim to your example, except the `_set_cell_text()` receives an additional `data` parameter. I'm getting 3 errors/warnings though: ``Warning: g_object_set_property: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed``, ``Warning: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed``, and ``gtk_list_store_get_value: assertion 'column < priv->n_columns' failed``. This last one occurs very often when interacting with the view.

Comment: @jpcgt I've now tested the code with GTK3 (and updated the answer accordingly), but I don't see any warnings, at least not on my machine with GTK 3.10.6. Do you get the warnings when running this minimal example, or in a larger program?

Comment: This is what I was doing wrong: I was creating the columns like this ``column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Name", renderer_text, text=1)``. The last parameter was causing the error. Works perfect now! Thanks.

Comment: Oh, by the way. I do things a little different: ``class MyClass(GObject.GObject, object):`` and then ``tree_store = Gtk.ListStore(MyClass)``. It works on my program, but for some reason this change breaks your example. It complains that the lambda function is getting None: ``view.append_column(make_column("First", lambda obj: obj.first)) \n AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first'``.

Comment: @jpcgt If you inherit from `GObject` and use `ListStore(MyClass)` then you are expected to define gobject-visible "properties" of `MyClass` and hook them to tree view columns. This is more complex than what your use case requires, which is why the answer uses `TYPE_PYOBJECT` list store. That way you can put any Python object in the store without having to define gobject-properties. In addition to that, the use of `set_cell_data_func` enables arbitrary Python properties to be snatched from the object. Were you able to salvage your example, or did you switch to the scheme provided by the answer?

Comment: Well, I'm using `class MyClass(GObject.GObject, object)` and `tree_store = Gtk.ListStore(MyClass)` and it is working (In my app, not the example). Have not looked into the differences, but it works.

Comment: @jpcgt It works until you introduce `set_cell_data_func`, if my understanding is correct? On the other hand, if you're not defining gobject properties on your object, or emitting signals, etc., then inheriting from `GObject` doesn't seem to actually buy you anything.