# How to sort a Gtk TreeView with custom column renderers?

Tags: python, sorting, treeview, gtk, pygtk

I have a `ListStore` which contains a custom object and a `TreeView` with several columns, each column has a special renderer which gets its information from various properties of my custom objects.

This example is directly inspired by [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825766):

```python
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

tree_store = Gtk.ListStore(GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT)
tree_store.append([MyClass("Roger", "Dupont", 15)])
tree_store.append([MyClass("Mike", "Doe", 100)])

def make_column(caption, getter):
    rend = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(caption, rend)
    def _set_cell_text(column, cell, model, it, ignored):
        obj = model.get_value(it, 0)
        cell.set_property('text', getter(obj))
    col.set_cell_data_func(rend, _set_cell_text)
    return col

view = Gtk.TreeView(tree_store)
view.append_column(make_column("First", lambda obj: obj.first))
view.append_column(make_column("Last", lambda obj: obj.last))
view.append_column(make_column("Age", lambda obj: '%d' % obj.age))
view.append_column(make_column("Full Name", lambda obj: '%s %s' % (obj.first, obj.last)))

view.set_headers_clickable(True)

w = Gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
w.add(view)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Now, I would like to be able to sort the columns of my `TreeView`, depending on the content of the columns displayed; so I would like to be able to sort by age, full name, first name and last name.

I can't use `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_sort_column_id` because it wants the ID of the column in the `ListStore` although I would like to have the ID of the column in the `TreeView`.

How to do that?

Edit: for performance reasons (my store is very large, formatting all the items before insertion takes a long time and formatting the values only a display is a reasonable trade off), I do **NOT** want to extend my `ListStore` to add more columns with the formatted values.

Comment: What you need to do is store your formatted data into the ListStore.

Comment: For some reasons, I would like NOT to store these formatted data into the `ListStore`, if that's possible.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I just edited my post to reflect why I would not like to add the formatted data into the `ListStore`, thanks for mentioning this, I forgot to add it earlier.

Comment: You don't want to format all items because it's expensive but you expect a component to be able to sort the values based on the formatted items? That does not seem reasonable... Can you provide an example of the values?

Comment: @multani I don't think you can. The filtering/sorting only knows about the liststore - not about any rendering.

Comment: @jku Hmmm, you are right, I didn't think about that before. Although if I want to sort on one column, I just need the data for that column (I don't have to compute the rest) and I could afford some latency when sorting... I'm trying to fix [this](https://github.com/multani/sonata/issues/47).

Comment: @multani if you can do just the comparison _much_ faster than you can do the actual formatting, then you could consider writing your own GtkTreeIterCompareFunc -- depending on the case this might be quite a bit faster.