# How to inherit from GObject class?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gobject

I want to write application with a tree view widget in witch I will store my objects of class 'Item'.

I know that in order to do so my 'Item' class must inherit from GObject class. Unfortunately something is wrong and I don't see text of items on my tree. I only get this warning:

```
Warning: unable to set property 'text' of type 'gchararray' from value of type '__main__+Item'
```

What I will have to do to fix this?

This sample program is demonstrates problem and it's ready to test fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject


class Item(GObject.GObject):
    text = GObject.property(type=str, default='item', flags=GObject.PARAM_READWRITE)

    def __init__(self, title):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.__title = title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__title

GObject.type_register(Item)


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        self.connect('destroy', self.on_destroy)
        tree_model = Gtk.TreeStore(Item.__gtype__)
        # tree_model = Gtk.TreeStore(str)
        text_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        text_column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(None, text_renderer)
        text_column.add_attribute(text_renderer, 'text', 0)
        tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(tree_model)
        tree_view.append_column(text_column)
        self.add(tree_view)
        self.show_all()
        tree_model.append(None, (Item('test'),))
        # tree_model.append(None, ('It works!',))

    def on_destroy(self, e):
        Gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GtkCellRendererText` requires string (`gchararray`) data for its `text` property, and it is receiving custom GObject values. The `__str__` function works on the Python level and is never invoked by GObject.

Fortunately, what you want to achieve doesn't require subclassing GObject. You need to do the following:

- Specify the tree store column as `GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT`. This will allow you to append your instances to the tree store without inheritance from `GObject` or special properties.
- Use `set_cell_data_func` on the tree view columns to extract textual data from your instances stored in the model.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22847402/1600898) for a working example of this technique.

Comment: I'm trying to do this too, but I cannot use `set_cell_data_func` as soon as I create the treeview (missing data that should be appended later, dynamically). Is it normal to have the warning still showing up as long as `set_cell_data_func` is not used?

Comment: @zezollo If the data is missing, then your data func should return the empty string (or whatever is appropriate until it becomes available). The warning from the question indicates that the program contains an error.